# Hi , I need to make line graphs in Ionic 2 , what is the best plugin for that?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, graph, ionic2, ionic3

I need to make line graphs in Ionic 2 , what is the best plugin for that ?
Here is an image of the graph I want to make [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ECK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you have 3 options:

1. Highcharts
2. D3
3. chartJs

All three are easy to install and use. for example for highcharts just run `npm install highcharts --save` and in your **page.ts** `import * as Highcharts from "Highcharts/highstock";`

and just declare your chart and its container.

```js
//add this code in ionViewDidLoad(){}
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<!-- add this your in your page html ,forget the code above -->


<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng2-highcharts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-highcharts) with ionic2 to achieve the same.

> npm install --save ng2-highcharts

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1wZSlICye2d67PJKOOJP?p=preview)**